# Network and portforwarding TCP, UDP

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpclient

How would one go about setting up a server and a client using TCP or UDP without the need of portforwarding on the client side?

A general **scenario** between a server and a client, say you made a simple game and you wanted them to be able to talk to each other without the need for portforwarding especially on the client side. (Client as usual behind firewall and router like a typical/user gamer would be)

Comment: I think you'll need to describe what you're looking for in more detail. Port forwarding would require something between the machines (some kind of router normally, which you're not describing) and you're not saying who needs to initiate the connection or what you're using it for.

Comment: If both machines can communicate directly, no port-forwarding needed.

Comment: What do you mean with directly?

Comment: OK. If "client as usual behind firewall and router", then, as usual, it should have also some NAT or something to go through firewall/router. You should explain first why this base scenario is not applied to your case.

Comment: I have read tons of articles and tutorials about TCP and udp connections, I'm just trying to understand the concept, not a piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take sample setup. Your server is behind router/firewall, so it has no public IP-address and could not accept connections directly. By this reason you make your router (which has public IP-address) to forward some port (i.e. data from incoming connections to some of its ports from big Internet) to some port of your server. The only requirement for the client is to be able to reach router's public IP. Just like any other Internet-address.

P.S. Your router is better to have static IP-address in big Internet, so the clients could find it easily.

Comment: Thanks for all the good help! Enlightened me a lot!  For anybody reading this, a more in-depth discussion is in the comments.